# Homepage loses page size when going to the second page

Tags: bug

There's a bug on the homepage: It loses its page size configuration when going to the second page. Just wanted to let you know.

I also wonder why there has to be the option for smaller page sizes anyway. I wonder what anyone would use this for. In my life I have never wanted a small page size on any site.

I mean this element of the homepage:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "loses page size configuration"?

Comment: The page size resets to 15 even if 50 was the old page size.

Comment: Ahh, I see. -----

Comment: I assume you're using new-nav, as I tested this without new-nav and didn't see the same issue. Once you set the page size back, it doesn't seem to change again unless you refresh/leave the page and come back.